# Checkbox in Finish Dialog

Tags: checkbox, registry, advanced-installer

I'm fairly new to **Advanced Installer** and I would like to have a `Checkbox` in the *finish install* dialog **only**. When the user checks the `Checkbox`, it should change a registry value in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key and If he unchecks the `Checkbox`, it should change it as well.

How do I achieve something like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Talking about MSI packages in general.** All system changes performed by an MSI installation are done before you get to *Finish* dialog. More exactly the changes start occurring the moment you enter InstallExecute sequence, i.e. you press "*Install*" button.

When you see the *Finish* dialog you are already back in the InstallUI sequence, so no more system changes are done by the installer at this phase.

*To read* - [MSI installation actions diagram - article](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-actions.html).

This being said, using the support from Registry page in Advanced Installer to create that entry if the checkbox on *Finish* dialog is selected is not possible. If it is mandatory for this checkbox to be at the end, then you need to write your own [custom action and execute it when the **Finish** button is hit](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-execute-ca.html).

My recommendation is to have this option presented to the end-user before they get to **InstallVerifyDlg** dialog, i.e. before the *Install* button is hit.

Doing this is quite easy, all you need is to [set a condition on the component of that registry entry](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=21473) (after you define it in Registry page) using the public property attached to your checkbox. The linked forums thread explains how to set a condition on a file installation, but the same applies for the registry entry.